# Flutter image from asset

Tags: flutter

I am trying to do an mobile app in flutter and everytime I try to add a photo I get an error like: " Failed assertion line 134 pos 15: 'assetName != null':is not true.
I observe that I didn't have the asset folder so I created it and add photos png in it. It's the problem with the size of the photos? or what?I also uncomment that #assetcode line  from pubspec.yaml[error photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUOY6.png)

```
assets:
- assets/burger.png
```

```css
import '../models/category_model.dart';

final categories = [
  Category(
    numberOfItems: 57,
    imagePath: "assets/burger.png",
    categoryName: "Legume"
  ),
```

category model

```css
class Category{
final String categoryName;
final String imagePath;
final int numberOfItems;

Category({this.categoryName,this.imagePath,this.numberOfItems});

}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code for the category_model wherein imagePath is being used?

Comment: yes @AxesGrinds I did it

Comment: Be careful with spaces in pubspec.yaml.. I’ve noticed you have no space before ‘-‘

Comment: delmin is right, make sure that the output of `flutter pub get` (runs when you save `pubspec.yaml`) is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

The indentation on the file **pubspec.yaml** is very important to import the packages or files correctly.

To import your image, you have to put more two spaces in **- assets/burger.png**

Try:

```
 assets:
    - assets/burger.png
```

---

If you need to import all the images in this folder you could do:

```
 assets:
    - assets/
```

For more information, consult the documentation: [Flutter - Assets And Images](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that pubspec.yaml has corrent indentation.

```
  assets:      // two spaces before assets. 
  - assets/     // two spaces before - and a space after -. This assets is for folder name.
```

First assets is for system. It remains constant. The second assets is your folder name. It depends based on your folder name.

If you want to access just a subfolder `images` inside `assets` folder,

```
  - assets/images/
//or
  - assets/images/burger.png
```

Hope this works for you.